# Read all files in directory except

Tags: php

The function below returns an array of XML files from a given directory including all subdirectories. How can I modify this function by passing a second optional parameter which excludes a directory.

```
E.g: 
getDirXmlFiles($config_dir, "example2");

Directory/Files
    /file1.xml
    /file2.xml
    /examples/file3.xml
    /examples/file4.xml
    /example2/file5.xml
    /example2/file5.xml
```

In the above case the function would return all files except files in the example2 directory.

```
function getDirXmlFiles($base) {        

    $files = array();       
    if(!is_dir($base)) return $files;

    if ($handle = opendir($base)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file == "." || $file == "..") continue;

            if(is_dir("$base/$file")) {                 
                $subfiles = $this->getDirXmlFiles("$base/$file");
                $files = array_merge($files, $subfiles);                    
            } else {                    
                if(Cms_File::type($file,false) == "xml") 
                    $files[] = "$base/$file";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine the function inputs:

```
function getDirXmlFiles($base, $excludeDir) {
```

Then change this line:

```
if(is_dir("$base/$file")) {
```

to this:

```
if(is_dir("$base/$file") && "$base/$file" != "$base/$excludeDir") {
```

Comment: first youre creating 2 new strings for testing when you could test only the "moving" parts `$file != $excludeDir` , second this solution will exclude files on on the first level directory only and not on lower subdirectories `$this->getDirXmlFiles("$base/$file", $excludeDir);` , third you should convince novices to concatenate strings proprely ( with `.` operator ) for best practices, fourth you should convince novices to concatenate strings only once not everytime they are needed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getDirXmlFiles($base, $exclude = NULL) {        

    $files = array();       
    if(!is_dir($base)) return $files;

    if ($handle = opendir($base)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file == "." || $file == ".." || "$base/$file" == $exclude) continue;

            if(is_dir("$base/$file")) {                 
                $subfiles = $this->getDirXmlFiles("$base/$file",$exclude);
                $files = array_merge($files, $subfiles);                    
            } else {                    
                if(Cms_File::type($file,false) == "xml") 
                    $files[] = "$base/$file";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: this will exlude a certan directory only if the full path to the directory is sent, not a certan directory name

Answer (score 0):

You can just slightly modify the function to check and see if the current directory is the one you want to exclude or not

```
function getDirXmlFiles($base,$exclude) {        

    $files = array();       
    if(!is_dir($base)) return $files;

    if ($handle = opendir($base)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file == "." || $file == "..") continue;

            if(is_dir("$base/$file") && $file != $exclude) {                 
                $subfiles = $this->getDirXmlFiles("$base/$file",$exclude);
                $files = array_merge($files, $subfiles);                    
            } else {                    
                if(Cms_File::type($file,false) == "xml") 
                    $files[] = "$base/$file";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Smth of the sort ( tested only the syntax validation there might be needed some small debugging ) ( this will allow you to exclude multiple directory names )

```
function getDirXmlFiles($base, $excludeArray = array()) {    

    if (!is_array($excludeArray))
        throw new Exception(__CLASS__ . "->" . __METHOD__ . " expects second argument to be a valid array");

    $files = array();       
    if(!is_dir($base)) return $files;

    if ($handle = opendir($base)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

            $path = $base . "/" . $file;
            $isDir = is_dir($path);

            if (
                $file == "."
                || $file == ".."
                || (
                    $isDir
                    && count($excludeArray) > 0 
                    && in_array($file, $excludeArray)
                )
            ) 
                continue;

            if($isDir) {                 
                $subfiles = $this->getDirXmlFiles($path, $excludeArray);
                $files = array_merge($files, $subfiles);                    
            } else {                    
                if(Cms_File::type($file,false) == "xml") 
                    $files[] = $path;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: I believe this answer would only work if the function belongs to an object and the script is running on PHP >= 5.0.0 (when the `__METHOD__` magic constant was introduced).

Comment: @JeffSlutz i assumed this function was belonging to a class since he calls the method ( function ) recursive with `$this->getDirXmlFil..`